# What could be a long and scenic two days backcountry ski tour in Switzerland, bivying on the snow?

Tags: winter, winter-camping, alps, winter-walking

I am a backcountry skier/snowshoes hiker and I finally want to do an overnight experience in the Alps.

The Simplon Dorf area would be ideal (for I can access it quite easily), but any southern Swiss Alps may be fine.

What I would love to do is a round trip (that is, getting back to the starting point by another route than the first day's), and I'd like to cover at least 2000 meters of ascent, but if the scenery is worthy even a less exerting tour may be great.

Comment: can you modify your question that it's not anymore opinion-based?

Comment: It might be better to ask places to avoid / areas which might require safety / if there are planned routes you can follow. Does still come across as asking for opinions.

Comment: after all that's what I'm after to. Well, let's delete it if it's not a proper question for the site.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you cannot delete it, it can only be closed.

Comment: @Dakatine get a guide book, there are tons of tours which are following your specs...

Comment: Really? I have plenty of guidebooks and they only mention daily trips. Bivying in the snow is quite uncommon if not extremely rare here.

Comment: @Dakatine Ah OK you already checked the books. You might be right that the books aren't specifically describing two day tours without staying at a hut. A reason could be that this isn't allowed by definition (strictly said you should only bivy as an emergency). If I'd be planning such a tour I would choose two or three normal daily trips and merge them. Of course you have to be able to find a good place for the night. But asking simply for long and scenic/beautiful round-tours, just take a book or a map and choose a route. Most parts in the Alps are beautiful :D

Comment: @Dakatine you can search for two tours which lead to the same peek on a different route. For Switzerland i would use the following websites www.skitouren.ch or www.hikr.org.

Comment: It's a good suggestion, thanks, but I should find two tours that reach the same peak on different routes and **by the same starting point**, 'cause I'll need to get back to it in the end. This narrows the search a lot, if that's even possible in normal books. Also, this would be like splitting a day tour (although by a different route on the way back) on two days, because we are talking about day tours, rather than actually using a whole day to reach the end.

Comment: There are a lot of tours you can do in Switzerland and use the public transport like the postal buses. So you could start on a point, go to a peak, go down to a different path and then go with the bus to your starting point.

Comment: this, sir, is an amazing answer. I never thought of it. Gonna check the timetables - and, if I may get onboard with skis and everything actyally. You just made my day.

Comment: I'm glad that this helped. This normally works fine. I travel quite often with my touring gear in these buses.